Express timeout based on custom time for CI/CD Pipeline
My express application is called from a CI/CD pipeline, I allow the senders to add a "timeout" value in the body of their POST. If the processing time exceeds that value, I want to send them back a 408 to break their pipeline. I'm having problems getting this to work:
      // Set the timeout to the timeout passed with the request
      req.setTimeout(timeout * 1000, () => {
        res.status(408).send('timed out').end();
      });

This just returns an ECONNRESET error with an undefined response body. How can I return a 408 with a "timed out" response body?
